# Register after admin auth in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

I want to have the registration after the auth, so the admin could create a user.I tried to find something about that but all examples are in Laravel 5s and the methodes of the controllers aren't the same.
Have you an idea,please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new user as an admin, you just have to use the `User::create([ ... ])` method. Remeber to put an email and a hashed password, such that the user can log in.

Example for user creation:

```
User::create([
  'email' => 'foo@bar.com',
  'password' => bcrypt('foobar'),
]);
```

If you want to remove the registration for guests, you should remove the RegistrationController and change the route to `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`.

Comment: ,ok,so the creation of the  user must be in another controller?I have a regController.php(for registration that didn't work) can I put the User::create([.... there?

Comment: You should be able to call `User::create` anywhere. Remember to add `use App\User;` to the top.

Answer (score -1):

Its common for administrators to create users for their application. You have to be carefull with the creating of user. I personally dont want a administrator that creates a password for my account.

I would do the following:

1.Create a user with a temporary password.

```
public function create(){
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = Hash::make(Str::random(32));
    $user->regToken = Str::random(32);
}
```

2.Save the user with a temporary password and send a registration email to the new user so he can change his password.

```
$user->notify(new MailCompleteRegistrationNotification($user->regToken, $user->email));
```

I use mail notifications to send the registration mail. in the notification i have the following tomail function.

```
 public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject("Subject")
            ->line('Welcome to the application. We created a account for you but still need some details.')
            ->line('If you want to complete the registration you can click the button below:')
            ->action('Complete registration', url('registration',  [$this->regToken,  $this->email]));
    }
```

I would recommend doing the user creation like that